# OpenSMTPD from address rewrite

Tags: linux, smtp, postfix, headers, email-filter

I am trying to use OpenSMTPD to re-write all instances of the from-address in an email header.   Here's the scenario I'm trying to solve for...

I have an email distribution list that various people use.  Some are users within my domain (ie. mydomain.com) and others are users outside of my domain (ie. gmail/hotmail/etc.com).

The issue is that my email relay provider will only relay emails coming from my domain.  When users send to the distribution list, it is relayed to everyone on the list, but if the "from" address is not from my domain, the relay provider bounces it.  ie. The mail server (Postfix) forwards the email to the list as if it came directly from the sender, so the from-address remains unchanged.

What I am looking to do it take any email addresses not in my domain and rewrite them to look like they are from my domain.  For example, it would rewrite an email from joe@gmail.com to joe@mydomain.com for every instance where joe@gmail.com might appear in the email header.

joe@mydomain.com is a valid address, it's just not the one the user uses day-to-day and I need to catch the cases where they don't use it.

I've seen examples of OpenSMTPD rules where it will rewrite all from addresses to the same new address (ie. noreply@mydomain.com), but I need something more dynamic.

I'm new to OpenSMTPD and haven't been able to find examples on how to do this.

The tricky part is correcting all instances within the header while leaving the rest of the header data intact.

If anyone can help, it would be appreciated.  I'm also not opposed to something other than OpenSMTPD if there's a better way to do it (ie. Postfix, sendmail, etc).